# Load route from iOS native code (objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm integrating an iOS native library. The library opens a third party app, this process data and reload my app using deep, the lib catches the response. I wanna load the JS screen component from the native Objective-C code integrated.

I tried to use the `RCTLinkingManager` but I don't know how to get the application instance and options.

```
[RCTLinkingManager application:app openURL:url options:options];
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, finding in React Native source code I founded the solution.

`RCTLinkingManager.application` uses the `postNotificationWithURL` function lo load an URL in the app.

```
...
static NSString *const kOpenURLNotification = @"RCTOpenURLNotification";

static void postNotificationWithURL(NSURL *URL, id sender)
{
  NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *payload = @{@"url": URL.absoluteString};
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kOpenURLNotification
                                                      object:sender
                                                    userInfo:payload];
}
...
```

So, that's it! Calling that function you can load a js screen component. It also works with react navigation.